# Python: Plotly: Parallel Coordinates Opacity

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, plotly

Im trying to do a parallel coordinate plot. I want the color of the lines black, but with an opacity so that lines which overlap are darker than the rest. Is it possible to set an opcaity to the color in the example of plotly parallel coordinates ?

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bcdunbar/datasets/master/parcoords_data.csv")

data = [
    go.Parcoords(
        line = dict(color = df['colorVal'],
                   colorscale = 'Jet',
                   showscale = True,
                   reversescale = True,
                   cmin = -4000,
                   cmax = -100),
        dimensions = list([
            dict(range = [32000,227900],
                 constraintrange = [100000,150000],
                 label = 'Block Height', values = df['blockHeight']),
            dict(range = [0,700000],
                 label = 'Block Width', values = df['blockWidth']),
            dict(tickvals = [0,0.5,1,2,3],
                 ticktext = ['A','AB','B','Y','Z'],
                 label = 'Cyclinder Material', values = df['cycMaterial']),
            dict(range = [-1,4],
                 tickvals = [0,1,2,3],
                 label = 'Block Material', values = df['blockMaterial']),
            dict(range = [134,3154],
                 visible = True,
                 label = 'Total Weight', values = df['totalWeight']),
            dict(range = [9,19984],
                 label = 'Assembly Penalty Weight', values = df['assemblyPW']),
            dict(range = [49000,568000],
                 label = 'Height st Width', values = df['HstW']),
            dict(range = [-28000,196430],
                 label = 'Min Height Width', values = df['minHW']),
            dict(range = [98453,501789],
                 label = 'Min Width Diameter', values = df['minWD']),
            dict(range = [1417,107154],
                 label = 'RF Block', values = df['rfBlock'])
        ])
    )
]

py.offline.plot(data, filename = 'parcoords-advanced')
```

Answer (score -1):

`plotly  2.1.0` needs `import plotly as py`

It looks impossible. The reason is as the follows for there is no any option that is related to "opacity":

Valid attributes for 'line' at path ['line'] under parents ['parcoords']:

```
['autocolorscale', 'cauto', 'cmax', 'cmin', 'color', 'colorbar',
'colorscale', 'colorsrc', 'reversescale', 'showscale']
```

Valid attributes for 'dimension' at path ['dimensions'][3] under parents ['parcoords', 'dimensions']:

```
['constraintrange', 'label', 'range', 'tickformat', 'ticktext',
'ticktextsrc', 'tickvals', 'tickvalssrc', 'values', 'valuessrc',
'visible']
```

However https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/ mentioned "opacity" that might be in another package of `plotly`

You can try R's plot or matplotlib.pyplot

Comment: What about the line "color" parameter? The documentation specifies that it accepts rgba colors but it doesn't work

Comment: Bit outdated but [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3964#issuecomment-502110263)